# Website hosting in specific folder on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any way on AWS S3 to host a website inside a specific folder ?

Example: http://my-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ pointing to /build folder.

Thanks in advance,

Pierre

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. You can.

If you integrate with AWS CloudFront, you will set the CloudFront distribution's Origin Domain Name as your S3 Bucket's Static Website Hosting Endpoint and the Origin Path to the index.html file inside the build folder.

Comment: Hi, this answer helps me. I was wondering if you could tell me what if I need to update my website. just change the files and we good to go? or do I have to re-initialize every time I need to update.

Answer (score 3):

No, the website must be in a bucket, and the bucket must match the domain. Files within the website can live in folders, but the root must be at the bucket's top level.