# Error when hosting website using AWS S3 and Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I am currently using an S3 bucket to store my website files and using Route53 for a custom domain name. However, I am getting this error when I visit my site:

```
404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: index.html
RequestId: *ReqestId*
HostId: *HostId*
```

My S3 bucket has one object which is the build folder for my website, which I created using `npm run build`. I've tried using a really simple index.html file instead of my actual website and it seems to work fine. I am unsure where to proceed from here. Anyone have experience with hosting websites like this and can point me in the right direction?

Also want to add that this is indeed a static website.

Comment: Hi Simey,

Could you please provide more details about Frontend framework you're using,. Could you also attach a file structure you've uploaded to S3 bucket?

`index.html` is a index file that is requested by default and should be present unless you have custom rules in place.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177435/website-hosting-in-specific-folder-on-aws-s3

Comment: @IlyaKhrustalev I am using react.js and inside the build folder is the index.html file, a static folder, and a few other files like pngs

Comment: I see, in this case your fix would be really simple. You just need to upload contents of `build/` folder directly to the root of your S3 bucket.

Here is an `awscli` command you can use:
`aws s3 sync ./build/ s3://<s3_bucket_name>/`

You could run it from your project root if you have your AWS credentials configured

Comment: @IlyaKhrustalev Thank you for this. This solved my problem!